# A population has a known average $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find the lower limit of the acceptance region for a significance of 10%

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider a normal population with average $\mu$ and variance
>   $\sigma^2$. To test the hypotheses
>
> $H_0: \mu = 10\\ H_1:\mu\neq 10$
>
> a sample of 16 has been obtained. What is the inferior limit of the acceptance region of the statistical test for a significance level of 10%?

I assume I have to find the p-value but I don't know how to do it without any more information. I need at least the sample mean and the population variance, I think. Help?

EDIT: Actually I think what I need to find is $Z_{\alpha} = 0.539828$. Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly is known, $\sigma^2$? I suppose that $\mu$ is not known, as otherwise there is nothing to test.

Comment: @PeterFranek The variance is known.

Comment: Ok, so assuming that the mean is $\mu=10$, which distribution has the average of 16 measurements?

Comment: @PeterFranek I'm not sure what you mean? I calculated the lower limit as $Z_{\alpha}$. Is this what I am supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know what you are supposed to do. I'm trying to understand your question. What exactly do you want to do with the 16 measurements?

Comment: @PeterFranek I don't know. That's all the question says. It says I have a normal population, the variance is known (so I know I am not supposed to use a t-student distribution), a sample of 16 was taken, and now I want the lower limit of the acceptance region for a significance of 10%. This is all the question says.

Comment: I see. But you know, this is not a forum for solving homework problems. Maybe try to improve the question via describing what you don't understand and your attempts on understanding.

Comment: @PeterFranek I edited my post and added a proposed solution. Is it correct and if not, why?

Comment: How did you get $Z_{\alpha} = 0.539828$? What is the known variance?

Comment: @Henry The problem doesn't say, it only says that it is know. I assume it's so I know I am supposed to use a normal distribution instead of a t-student one.

Comment: $\Phi(\frac1{10}) \approx 0.539828$ but that does not look like a useful approach

Comment: @StubbornAtom The information I am looking for is "The inferior limit of the acceptance region of the statistical test for a significance level of 10%". I copied it verbatim. That's all it says.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing in doing this? What is the rejection region? Hence what is the acceptance region?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I just don't understand what I am supposed to do. The rejection region is $Z_0 <-Z_{\alpha} \Leftrightarrow Z_0 < - 0.539828$. Even if I do $Z_0 = \frac{x-10}{\sigma/4}$ I can't solve this.

Comment: Your subject line says the average is "known", but then you start by proposing to test hypotheses on the value of the average. To say the average is "known" in this context conventionally rules out any such hypothesis tests. You don't test the hypothesis that $\mu=10$ when you KNOW that $\mu=10. \qquad$

Comment: @Segmentationfault from the discussion, my estimate is that the problem is not in this particular exercise, but more like you don't understand basic definitions and concepts. But then maybe some elementary textbook or online course is a good point to start, way before you come to "confidence intervals" topics.

Answer (score 2):

So assume we have the 16 measurements, $x_1,\ldots, x_{16}$. You are correct that we will need the sample mean $\bar{x}$. If $\sigma^2$ is known, we won't even need the sample variance (or at least I'm not sure how we would use it).

In general, if the mean $\bar{x}$ is very far from 10, we will reject the hypothesis. If the mean $\bar{x}$ is not too far from 10, we will not reject the hypothesis.

Can you describe the distribution of $\bar{x}$? Can you find an interval $[10-a, 10+a]$ so that the mean would be with 90 % probability in this interval, assuming $H_0$?

Comment: $10*.1 = 1 = a$?

Answer (score 1):

Note your hypothesis is a two tail test therefore the  inferior limit will be the quantile at $5\%$ of your statistic distribution under the null hypothesis. Your rejection region are the upper and lower tails that account for $10\%$ of the probability of the null distribution. If you find the upper bound of the lower tail rejection region you have  found your lower limit of the acceptance  region.

If population  variance is known your statistic  will be

$$\frac{\bar{X}-10}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\sim N(0,1)$$

Find the  quantile of a standard normal at $5\%$ which is -1.64.

If population variance is not known your statistic will be: 
$$\frac{\bar{X}-10}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}\sim t(n-1)$$

where $S$  is the sample variance and $n-1$ are the degrees of freedom  so if  we find the  quantile of this distribution under the null.  the  lower  rejection region is  -1.75.